# Linux shell autocompletion and CMake intermediate target

Tags: linux, makefile, autocomplete, cmake

I am facing an issue on a project using CMake :

I defined some target (less than 10) and my project consists of ~120 files. When generating Makefile, CMake create a additional target for intermediate files (`.o`, `.i`, `.s`) for each source file. Leading to at least 350 targets. So `make` command autocompletion became extremely slow.

Is there a way to disable this CMake behaviour / to hide these targets ?

Thank you.